# sqlcipher-for-android-v3.5.6.zip download or latest binaries for sqlcipher for android - Marshmallow devices

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-sdk-tools, sqlcipher-android

I am planning to integrate sqlcipher in my existing android application. Where can I download the latest sqlcipher-for-android-v3.5.6.zip or binaries for sqlcipher for android? Please note that my application target SDK is point to Marshmallow or greater OS devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gradle build :

```
compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.6@aar'
```

here is the complete tutorial of android sqlcipher integration

https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/

Comment: this is the efficient  way how most of them include libraries.